# Why am I getting regular http requests for rpix.php on my AWS server

Tags: http, amazon-aws

Recently Ive redeployed by Java application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk running within a Tomcat container. I now keep getting messages like:

```
Message: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Degraded. 9.1 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.
```

due to the new **Health** monitor.

I have downloaded the logs and the only http 500 errors I can find are in localhost for an attempt to access **rpix.php**

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2015:05:07:40 +0000] "GET /rpix.php?id=253 HTTP/1.1" 500 1728
```

Ive no idea what rpix.php is ?

Is this related to my server being on AWS, or just some random attempt by some one to lookup a non-existent url.

Can I/Should I block this url request before it even gets to my tomcat instance ?

Comment: If you don't know what the request is, it shouldn't be resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error.   Unknown requests should result in a 404 Not Found Error.  Something must be installed on your server that is handling the request.   It could be something you forgot about, something AWS related, or something malware related.

Comment: Its not someething Ive installed, my guess is because the url ends with .php that this causes it try an invoke a php intepreter, but tomcat doesnt support .php and that causes the internal error

Comment: I have tomcat 7 installed locally and it gives a 404 for that URL path:  http://i.imgur.com/xKiZKUd.png  I don't know of anything in Tomcat that tries to react to php file extension by default.

Comment: Okay but its nothing Ive done I just deploy a war to the ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat server provided by AWS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Ok stand corrected, I put the query in to browser, and now getting a stacktrace that shows the 500 error is caused by my java code calling response.sendError() twice instead of returning after the first call. So fixed that, but the main question remains why are they sending such a request to my server, and can I/should I block it before it gets to tomcat